# Hamiltonian density of Abelian-Higgs Lagrangian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, hamiltonian-formalism, classical-field-theory

Given the Lagrangian density
$$\mathcal{L}=-(\nabla^{\mu}\phi)^\dagger(\nabla_\mu \phi)-\frac{\lambda}{4}\left(\phi^{\dagger}\phi-v^2\right)^2-\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}\,,\quad \nabla_\mu\phi=\partial_\mu\phi-iqA_\mu\phi, $$
how can one find the Hamiltonian density from this? I try using
$$ \mathcal{H}= \dot{\phi}\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{\phi}}+\dot{\phi}^\dagger\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{\phi}^\dagger}+\dot{A}_\mu \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{A_\mu}}-\mathcal{L}$$

The scalar field terms are straightforward but the conjugate field of $A_\mu$ seems to vanish and I feel like it shouldn't. Is the above formula correct? I feel like i'm looking over something simple.

Comment: Can you write the third term in your Hamiltonian  explicitly?

Comment: Can you understand the Legendre transformation for Maxwell theory? If so, there is no conceptual difference needed to apply it here.

Comment: @CosmasZachos The problem is that $\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{A_\mu}}=0$ which means that the gauge field $A_\mu$ does not have a conjugate momentum. This is the thing that bothers me.

Comment: @ConnorBehan Do you maybe have a link to something? Googling Legendre transformation for Maxwell theory only results in thermodynamics stuff.

Comment: You are wrong, of course.  Find the canonical momentum for spacelike $\mu=i$.